# CUDA 2D array assignment

Tags: c, cuda

I have a strange problem dealing with 2D array on CUDA device.

```
    #define VR 100 // rows
    #define ST 13 // columns
    __global__ void test(float *arr, curandState *globalState, size_t pitch, unsigned long seed) {
    int id = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x)  + threadIdx.x;
    curand_init ( seed, id, 0, &globalState[id] );
    cuPrintf("Thread id: %d \n", id);

    float* row = (float*)(((char*)arr) + id * pitch);
    for (int j = 0; j < ST; ++j) {
        row[j] = generate(globalState, id);
    }

}

int main() {
    float *d_arr;
    float *h_arr = new float[VR*ST];
    size_t pitch;
    cudaMallocPitch(&d_arr, &pitch, ST* sizeof(float), VR);

    dim3 dimBlock(VR); 
    dim3 dimGrid(1,1);

    curandState* devStates;
    cudaMalloc ( &devStates, VR*ST*sizeof( curandState ) );

    test <<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>> (d_arr, devStates, pitch, unsigned(time(NULL)));
    cudaMemcpy(h_arr, d_arr,VR*ST*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i=0; i<VR; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<ST; j++) {
            cout << "N["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]=" << h_arr[(i*ST)+j]<<endl;
        }
    }
```

I don't get evenly distributed numbers, instead they appear in sequence of 13 with bunch of zeros in between. See: http://pastie.org/6106381

Comment: When does cuPrintf is actually executed/evaluated? Is it a synchronous call?

Comment: The printf buffer size is limited.   You appear to be trying to  generate 13*13*100 output lines from the kernel.  Printf from device is intended to be a limited-use debugging tool, not a general purpose output method.  What happens if you limit the printf to a single thread i.e. `if (id == 0) cuPrintf(...)` ?  Also your dimBlock and dimGrid parameters appear to be reversed in your kernel call.  The grid dimensions come first, followed by the block dimensions.  And the output format you are showing doesn't appear to match your cuPrintf lines, so is this the code you are actually running?

Comment: I would also recommend doing error checking on all cuda calls (and kernel calls).  If you reverse your grid and block parameters to fix that issue, you may find the GPU you are trying to run on does not support 1300 threads/block.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you for your input! I have fixed dimBlock and dimGrid order and now it works

Comment: I have updated my question. Please see above.

Comment: Where is `pitch` defined?  Please update your question to reflect the code you are actually running.  `id*pitch` doesn't look like an appropriate computation in your row pointer calculation in your kernel.  You appear to be launching a grid of 1300 threads.  Perhaps you should run this through cuda-memcheck, and you might discover some out of bounds accesses in your kernel.  You might also describe what your intentions are as to generation of kernels, size of data set, and mapping of threads to data elements.  Are you wanting each thread to handle a row of data?  How many rows do you want?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have update my code. Please see above. Yes, i want each kernel to handle the row data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24247/discussion-between-c4rrt3r-and-robert-crovella)

Comment: Where is `generate()` defined?  Can you actually post a complete, compilable example of your code, including #include files and everything needed to build the app.   After trying to hack together an app based on your code, and changing `generate()` to `curand()` I get a result that does not have any zeroes in the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem  is that the original data array is being allocated using `cudaMallocPitch` whereas the copying is being done using ordinary `cudaMemcpy`.  This will give unexpected results because the `cudaMallocPitch` operation creates "padded" rows to satisfy alignment requirements, whereas cudaMemcpy assumes everything is stored contiguously.  Below is code that I believe has corrections to be functional:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <curand_kernel.h>

    #define VR 100 // rows
    #define ST 13 // columns


__device__ float generate(curandState* globalState, int id)
{
    //int id = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x)  + threadIdx.x;
    curandState localState = globalState[id];
    float rand;
    do {
        rand = curand_uniform( &localState );
    } while(rand == 0); //
    globalState[id] = localState;
    return rand;
}


    __global__ void test(float *arr, curandState *globalState, size_t pitch, unsigned long seed) {
    int id = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x)  + threadIdx.x;
    curand_init ( seed, id, 0, &globalState[id] );
    //cuPrintf("Thread id: %d \n", id);

    float* row = (float*)(((char*)arr) + id * pitch);
    for (int j = 0; j < ST; ++j) {
        row[j] = generate(globalState, id);
    }

}

    using namespace std;
int main() {
    float *d_arr;
    float *h_arr = new float[VR*ST];
    size_t pitch;
    cudaMallocPitch(&d_arr, &pitch, ST* sizeof(float), VR);

    dim3 dimBlock(VR);
    dim3 dimGrid(1,1);

    curandState* devStates;
    cudaMalloc ( &devStates, VR*ST*sizeof( curandState ) );

    test <<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>> (d_arr, devStates, pitch, unsigned(time(NULL)));
    cudaMemcpy2D(h_arr, ST*sizeof(float),  d_arr, pitch, ST*sizeof(float), VR ,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i=0; i<VR; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<ST; j++) {
            cout << "N["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]=" << h_arr[(i*ST)+j]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling the above code using:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -lcurand  -o t70 t70.cu
```

and then running I get what appears to be "normal" output:

```
N[0][0]=0.876772
N[0][1]=0.550017
N[0][2]=0.49023
N[0][3]=0.530145
N[0][4]=0.501616
N[0][5]=0.326232
N[0][6]=0.438308
N[0][7]=0.857651
N[0][8]=0.462743
N[0][9]=0.38252
N[0][10]=0.258212
N[0][11]=0.194021
N[0][12]=0.895522
N[1][0]=0.559201
N[1][1]=0.257747
N[1][2]=0.430971
N[1][3]=0.707209
N[1][4]=0.599081
N[1][5]=0.0457626
N[1][6]=0.702412
N[1][7]=0.88791
N[1][8]=0.508877
N[1][9]=0.702734
N[1][10]=0.379898
N[1][11]=0.138841
N[1][12]=0.540869
```

(results truncated)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's wrong, you should assign VR number of threads or blocks because you already loop through ST in the kernel.

maybe that will fix it.